# Book about a girl with green hair who has special powers

Tags: story-identification, books

The intro starts off with describing her as having unique hair from other people and her parents say she is special, because those like her have certain abilities. They live in a plant technology based society and in a town surrounded by a large forest that no one dares enter because of the dangers. Don’t know the main character’s name but her friend gets bit and poisoned and she goes venturing out into the large forest to find a cure and in the end she discovers that she can fly and heads back to give him the cure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Zahrah the Windseeker*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008847PQW), by Nnedi Okorafor (then Okorafor-Mbachu).

[image]

The plant hair is clear from the cover.

The fact that she can fly is in the title: she's a Windseeker:

> My old old grandmother once told me that a few of these dada-born
> folks were born with the ability to fly. Windseekers, she used to call
> them. But she also told me that there were little blue men three
> apples high who lived in the mushrooms that grew in our backyard. I
> know a friend of a friend who knows two dada-born folks. He said
> neither of these individuals has ever left the ground without any
> help. So maybe my grandmother is not so reliable, but you can trust me
> when I say that this year’s most stylish will be wearing dada
> extensions.
>
> <sub>*Zahrah the Windseeker*</sub>

And the rest of what you mention is essentially the book blurb:

> Zahrah, a timid thirteen-year-old girl, undertakes a dangerous quest
> into the Forbidden Greeny Jungle to seek the antidote for her best
> friend after he is bitten by a snake, and finds knowledge, courage,
> and hidden powers along the way
>
> <sub>*Zahrah the Windseeker*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been itching me for a few.

Comment: @Elias If this answer is correct, you can accept it (by clicking the checkmark on the left) to mark the question as solved :-)